# CodeIgniter 3 upload image just reloading the page

Tags: codeigniter, image-uploading

I am trying to make an upload form but when I submit it, it just refreshes the form, does not even go back to the designated route and no message is shown. Here is my `add()` function:

```
public function add()
{
    if ($this->input->post()) {
        $data['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $data['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif';
        $data['max_size'] = '500';
        $data['max_width'] = '1024';
        $data['max_height'] = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $data);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('imagem')) {
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Imagem \'' . $image_data['file_name'] . '\' adicionada');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Erro: ' . $this->upload->display_errors());
        }

        redirect('/admin/banners', 'refresh');
    }

    $data['page'] = $this->config->item('admin_template_dir_admin') . '/banners/add';
    $data['module'] = 'admin';

    $this->load->view($this->_container, $data);
}
```

The form:

```
<form action="/admin/banners/adicionar" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <small>Imagens de até 1024x768</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="selecionar_imagem">Selecionar Imagem</label>
        <input type="file" name="imagem" required/>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Adicionar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: where is `adicionar()`??

Comment: The form action appears to be calling adicionar() instead of add()

Comment: @Ness That is my route name. I use the same pattern in other pages and it work well. The route then calls the controller `banner` and the method `add`. That is just for a friendly pt_BR URI.

Comment: Can you step through it and see if you get the flash messages set? if so what does the error say?

Comment: @Ness I do not get any flash message. It simply reloads the form. When I previously forgot to add the `enctype`, the error saying I must choose an image was shown, but now, nothing.

Comment: take out the if statement and see what you get.

Comment: @Ness Everything still the same. Even with a `die;` inside of the `if`, nothing happens.

Comment: Change if ($this->upload->do_upload('imagem'))      for.     if ($this->upload->do_upload())

Comment: @Ness I already tried both. I read that CodeIgniter seeks for a default name `userfile`, and if it should look for a different one, must be passed as parameter in `do_upload()`. :((

Comment: do all your other form action contain only the path to the function? of do they have the whole url?

Comment: @Ness Every other forms have the same pattern `admin/[controller]/adicionar` in the case of adding a new data. This route leads to the `add` function of the controllers. This is all for the sake of a nice pt_BR URI. I have tried to modify the `method` of this form, but the same thing happens.

Comment: can set a breakpoint in the add method, to see what the post values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95618/discussion-between-ness-and-mfgabriel92).

Comment: @Ness Sorry, I had to leave that time. I will try to do it, to set breakpoints.

Comment: @Ness Sorry, I did not manage to make XDebug work with Netbeans. Simply did not work.

Comment: can you do a var_dump ($_POST ); before the if statement

Comment: @Ness The result is odd. array "(size=0) empty".

Comment: that might the problem, is not getting the post data

Comment: @Ness It seems it does not even enter the `if` condition. I put some `echo` and I could only see the one before everything and after everything. Could a method to upload an image be different than I have been doing so far?

Comment: try changing the button in the form from <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Adicionar</button>   to. <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Adicionar" />

Comment: I made it. It seems I did have to modify the way I was doing the things. I had to create a separated method `upload()`, instead of doing that `if` thing inside of the same method I was rendering the view.

Answer (score 0):

I made it. It seems I did have to modify the way I was doing the things. I had to create a separated method `upload()`, instead of doing that `if` condition inside of the same method I was rendering the view.

```
public function add()
{
    $data['page'] = $this->config->item('admin_template_dir_admin') . '/banners/add';
    $data['module'] = 'admin';

    $this->load->view($this->_container, $data);
}

public function upload()
{
    $this->load->library('upload', array(
        'upload_path' => './uploads/',
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg',
        'max_size' => '5000',
        'overwrite' => true
    ));

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('imagem')) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Imagem de Banner adicionada');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Erro: ' . $this->upload->display_errors());
    }

    redirect('/admin/banners', 'refresh');
}
```

And then in the `form`, modify the `method` to `/admin/banners/upload`.